# How do I put legend for Na in sf_geom ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I'm trying to make a map with information of São Paulo. To do this I'm using geobr and ggplot2. But my dataset have lot of missing data (NA), and a want put legend box to NA values. My code to generate a graph is:

```r
ggplot(data= data, aes(geometry=geom)) +
  geom_sf(aes( fill=ite) ) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="white", high="green",
                      na.value = "red", 
                      ) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=NA)
```

[image]

Using geom_sf I couldn't put the legend box to NA values. The complete code is [here](https://github.com/mj-ribeiro/College-works/blob/master/monitoring_macro/esg_map.R). I apreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You should supply an example for us to work with (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I never worked with map objects and i could't test anything without an example, so this is probably off, but at least i can give some guesses:

The `fill` argument created a legend because it was passed as an `aes` argument, but it seems that `na.value` doesn't get interpreted like that.

I don't know how to apply to your code, but what you could do (alerta de gambiarra) is creating a column on your df that indicates if a value is `NA`, something like: `data$na <- is.na(data$'column with the values')`. Then you could use this to create another legend box by doing:

```
ggplot(data=data, aes(geometry=geom, color=na)) + ...
```

Which will set a color for `TRUE` and `FALSE`, but we only want a legend for the `TRUE` ones, as the others are already explained by the Fill scale. To make that right, we add:

```
scale_color_manual(breaks=c("TRUE"), values=c("red"))
```

Maybe you'll need to set two colors in `values`, but even then it should appear only `TRUE` in the legend.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, because color argument don't accept logical values or factors. In my question I put a short example but I put the link of code that is in my [GitHub](https://github.com/mj-ribeiro/College-works/blob/master/monitoring_macro/esg_map.R).

Comment: @MarcosJúnio i don't know then. As for the example, if i didn't missed it, you should also add some data for us to try applying what we think beforehand. Boa sorte!